# mysql userid password change

Tags: mysql

Am using wamp server,where in my project I need to change the userid and password of mysql.I want to change it to username:-"root" password:-"root123".How it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

you would need...

$ mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest way would be to log into phpMyAdmin and update the values in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Enter to WAMP mysql console and write:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

to remove old user

```
DROP USER 'olduser'@'localhost';
```

If you are using WAMP on grahical interface, right click on the system tray WAMP and check MySQL section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Just run (example under windows):

> - Win + r
> - cmd in the run box, hit enter
> - go to your wamp install dir and look for the mysql bin, eg.
>     "cd C:\wamp\apps\phpMyAdmin-3.3.3"
> - run: mysqladmin -uroot password NEWPASSWORD

and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to MySQL Console and then type this in the following prompt

```
mysql>update mysql.user SET password=password("newpass");
```

Press "**Enter Key**"

```
mysql>flush privileges;
```

Press "**Enter Key**"

**Restart MySQL Service.**